# How to align specific text with image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align only 1 paragraph to the right of an image as opposed to all paragraphs. Is there a way to do this without tables. Would using tables for this be considered poor design?

As it is right now both my paragraph and my article footer align to the right of an image. I would like my article footer to be below the image while the paragraph is to the right of the image.

```
echo '<article>';
echo '<header>';
echo '<h2><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></h2>'; 
echo '</header>';
echo '<p>Posted on '.date('jS M Y H:i:s', strtotime($row['postDate'])).'</p>';

echo '<p><img src="images/test.jpg" height="153" width="186" align="left">'.$row['postDesc'].'</p>';

echo '<footer>';
echo '<p><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">Read More</a></p>';
echo '</footer>';

echo '</article>';
```

Comment: Yes, using tables for this would be considered poor design.

Comment: Have you tried giving the <p> a class so you can just float:right; it?

Comment: When asking a question like this that has nothing to do with PHP, it is far easier to help you if you only post the resultant HTML. Also include the CSS you've already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest you to take the **lazy server** term into account: give all the workload that you can to the client (browser).

### Solution

Put your image and its description within a container element.

---

Set the `display` property of your `img` and description container element to `inline-block`.

---

### HTML

```
<div id="together">
    <img class="left" src="http://oi46.tinypic.com/wve6o6.jpg" />
    <div id="description" class="right">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```css
#together {
    border:3px solid #111;
}
.left {
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
    clear:left;
}
.right {
    display:inline-block;
    clear:right;
    margin-left:50px;   
    width:200px;
}
```

### [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/P3VYG/1/)

Answer (score 0):

It's not that simple. There is valign property, but in every browser it is being displayed in different way. Use `style="float:left"` on image instead of align, should do the job.